# Inverse image of affine open set on separated scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Soory for my bad English.

Let $X, Y$ be Noetherian separated scheme, and $f:X\to Y$ be morphism of scheme.

Let $U \subseteq Y$ be affine open subscheme.

Then, Is $f^{-1}(U)=X\times_Y U$ affine?

Tell me proof or counter example  ,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This need not be true in general as in the answer above.

But consider a morphism of schemes $f:X\longrightarrow Y$, where $X$ is an affine scheme and $Y$ a separated $\mathbb{Z}$-scheme. Then the pull-back $f^{-1}(V)$ of every affine open subset $V\subset Y$ is affine. (One does not need Noetherian hypothesis on the spaces.)

The canonical morphism $X\times_{Y}V \cong f^{-1}(V)\longrightarrow X\times _{\mathbb{Z}}V$ is a closed immersion since it is the base change of the diagonal morphism $\Delta_{Y/\mathbb{Z}}:Y\longrightarrow Y\times_{\mathbb{Z}}Y$ which is a closed immersion since $Y$ is separated over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Since $X\times _{\mathbb{Z}}V$ is an affine scheme, using the fact that closed subscheme of an affine scheme is affine, we can conclude that $f^{-1}(V)$ is an affine scheme.

Comment: Thank you very much. I resolved by your help.

Answer (score 2):

No, morphisms with that property are called affine, see e.g. [stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01S5). For a counterexample, just pick a non-affine Noetherian separated scheme over a field $k$ and consider the structure morphism to $\text{Spec}(k)$.

Comment: Thank you very much.